# Размер игры Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня игра , 40МБ весит.Создаю 8 сцен (уровней)(в сцене пару панелек) и при билде + 20Мб соответственно, выходит 60МБ как так то?Какие есть варианты для уменьшения размера?
(Недавно начал изучать Unity ,но опыт программирования есть )

Comment: Убери Static Batching на объектах

Answer (score 0):

Переключите формат сериализации ассетов с Binary на Text (*Edit - Settings -
 Editor Settings*) и откройте сцену блокнотом. И вы убедитесь что ничего сверхестественного в сцене нет, и что по сути вы ничего сделать не можете. Единственное дополнительно место могут занимать запечённые тени, или кеш GI. Отключить это всё можно в окне Window -> Light.

Вариант оптимизации может заключаться в вынесение основных данных в Serializable Objects что позволит использовать одно хранилище для всех сцен. Но это если есть повторяющиеся данные. Также вы можете снизить вес билда с помощью подгружаемых ресурсов (Asset Bundle)

Ещё замечу, что всё зависит от того, что вы используете в сцене. Если у вас там пара панелек в миллион полигонов и с огромной текстурой, то Unity включит это в билд и это даст вам те самые 20мб.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-EditorManager.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.html